# Xamarin Studio: permenantly hide the Application Output tab

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm running `Xamarin Studio` on a MacBook with comparatively low resolution. The `Application Output` tab appears every time I test my program, taking up valuable screen space waste and it's a waste of precious time to close it over and over.

In `Version 5.10.2 (Build 56)` I actually did manage to hide it permanently, but struggling to achieve that in `Version 6.1 (build 817)`. Any suggestions?